# Hierarchical path RegExp

Tags: regex

I have to remove a known "level" from a hierarchical path using a regular expression.
In other terms, I want to go from 'a/b/X/c/d' to 'a/b/c/d', where X can be at any level of the path.

Using Javascript as an example, I have crafted the following:

```
str = str.replace(/^(?:(.+\/)|)X(?:$|\/(.+$))/, "$1$2")
```

which works fine when X is either the root or is in the middle of the path, but leaves a trailing slash when X comes last in the path. I could make a subsequent replace to handle those instances, but would it be possible to create a better RegEx that matches all the cases?

Thanks.

**Edit**: To clarify, all levels of the path might contain any number of characters and I'm only interested in removing a level only if it matches X exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search: `\bX/|/X(?=$)`

Replace: Empty String

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/13)**, see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Input**

```
a/b/X/c/d
X/a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d/X
```

**Output**

```
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` assert word boundary
- `X/` match `X/`
- OR `|`
- Match `/X`, if the lookahead `(?=$)` can assert that what follows is the end of the string

Comment: I had a bug, now fixed. Let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: Tested and found a bug: 1X/a/b/c/d => 1a/b/c/d, I think ^X/|/X(?=/|$) is better.

Comment: @Chris I wrote the regex for one-letter folders as in the example, but you're right, let's take care of that problem anyway by adding a word boundary. Thank you. :)

Comment: This does not work when X appears as part of a level (as a postfix of another string in particular). Perhaps I should have clarified in the OP that folders might have any number of characters, not necessarily a single letter, sorry about that. Example: a/b/preX/c/d will transform to a/b/pre/c/d

Comment: Just to clarify, the RegExp should match the entire level: if the level is exactly X then it should remove that level, but otherwise it should leave it alone.

Comment: You said in the spec `I want to go from 'a/b/X/c/d' to 'a/b/c/d'`  Now you say you want to leave it alone. Not understanding.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If a level is exactly 'X' I want it removed (a/X/z -> a/z). If a level contains 'X' I don't want it removed (a/bX/z -> a/bX/z). I have edited the OP for clarification.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the regex does. Sorry, I had not updated the demo. Please look at it again and let me know if this is what you want. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, seems to work perfectly now! Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, I had to add a simple ^X$ alternative to the expression, to match the case where the entire path is simply X. The resulting expression is: \bX/|/X(?=$)|^X$. Thanks again.